# Why did CentOS 6.4 set up sendmail-related stuff up this way?

Tags: centos, sendmail

After my CentOS 6.4 install, sendmail-related components were set up as follows:

`mail:x:12:mail,postfix` in /etc/group

`drwx------ 2 root mail 4096 Sep  6 14:06 /var/spool/mqueue`

And I was getting these errors when invoking a shell script to send email with an attachment, but not a plain `mail -s "subject" recipient < /dev/null` on the command line

```
Sep  6 12:46:08 localhost sendmail[3554]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(ics): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/): Permission denied
```

This is what I did to fix the problem, but why did I have to do it, and what else could I have done? Those are my questions.

`mail:x:12:mail,postfix,smmsp` in /etc/group

`drwxrwx--- 2 root smmsp 4096 Sep  6 14:06 /var/spool/mqueue`

### Edit:

To make matters stranger, a CentOS 5.9 system set up just the way my system **was** set up works fine without the error.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/520531/sendmail-chdir-clientmqueue-permission-denied

Comment: Are you chrooted after installation?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I'm not sure what your comment means. On every other system I have, I installed, made sure sendmail was running and mail client was installed, and then any user can send mail off the box. It works now, but not until I tweaked the things indicated in the OP.

Comment: @CraigSanders That's the answer. If you put in something to that affect, I'll accept it.

Comment: ok, done.  btw, i'm not sure why you've tagged this 'postfix' because it's a question about sendmail, not postfix.

Comment: It was sendmail. I'll go retag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sendmail binary should be in group smmsp and setgid and /var/spool/mqueue should be group smmsp, and group writable.

```
chgrp smmsp /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
chmod a=rx,g+s /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail

chgrp smmsp /var/spool/mqueue
chmod ug=rwx,o= /var/spool/mqueue
```

see https://serverfault.com/questions/520531/sendmail-chdir-clientmqueue-permission-denied

As for the reason why - most likely a packaging bug.  Report it to the Centos developers so they can fix it.  http://bugs.centos.org